# C++ Removing a character at the end of a Deque sequence container output issue

Tags: c++, character, deque

I need help. So, I have to code ( C++ ) and execute a deque sequence container. For the output, between each integer, it is required that I include " & ". The output should look like this :

20 & 18 & 16 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 0

My issue is I got my desired output with " & " between every integer but because of this there is also an " & " at the end of the output. For example :

20 & 18 & 16 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 0 **&**

I want to get rid of the final " & " at the end of my output only. I could really use some help to solve this issue. Any tips would greatly be appreciated.

**Below is the full codes for this project :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

void display(deque <int> k)
{
deque <int> :: iterator it;
for (it = k.begin(); it != k.end(); ++it)
cout << *it << " & ";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
}
  
  
int main()
{
deque <int> dq;
int i;

for(i=0;i<=20;i+=2)
    {
        dq.push_front(i);
    }

cout<<"\nDeque aftet 1st operation: ";
display(dq);
for(i=101;i<=113;i+=4)
dq.push_front(i);


for(i=103;i<=115;i+=4)
dq.push_back(i);
cout<<"Deque aftet 2nd operation: ";
display(dq);


for(i=0;i<dq.size();i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
        {
            dq[i]=777;
        }
}
cout<<"Deque aftet 3rd operation: ";
display(dq);
  
  
//delete from dqueue
deque<int>::iterator it1, it2,it3,it4;
it1 = dq.begin();
it2 = dq.end();
//first three value
it3= it1+3;

//last three value
it4=dq.end();
it4--;
it4--;
it4--;   

dq.erase(it1,it3);
dq.erase(it4,it2);

cout<<"Deque aftet 4th operation: ";
display(dq);

return 0;
 
}
```

Comment: In the `display` try printing all but the last element of the deque. Then print the last separately without the trailing extra string.

Comment: It could work, I will try that. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Update! I found a solution. I used \b. So, it turns out like this :

```
void display(deque <int> k)
{
deque <int> :: iterator it;
for (it = k.begin(); it != k.end(); ++it) {
cout << *it << " & ";
}
cout << "\b\b \n";
}
```

\b is a backslash code (or character escape sequences).
\b is a backspace character it takes the cursor one character backward so that when you will type the next thing the characters ahead of the cursor will be overwritten.

Meaning if u print it, the cursor will print and come back 1 character.

For example

```
cout<<"hello\bHi";
```

will print "HellHi" because after printing Hello, the compiler found a \b escape sequence. So it came 1 character back (at 'o' of Hello) and start printing Hi from o of Hello. So u got HellHi instead of HelloHi.

I hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this issue just like I did in their codes and projects. Please correct me if I'm wrong or misunderstood the use of character escape sequences. I appreciate all the responses to this post. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
void display(deque <int> k)
{
    deque <int> :: iterator it = k.begin();
    if ( it != k.end() ) {
        count << *it ++;
    }
    
    for ( ; it != k.end(); ++it) {
        cout << " & " << "\n\n" << *it;
    }
}
```